# Vuetify: How to remove vertical spacing from v-menu list?

Tags: vuetify.js

I have created a `v-menu` containing some buttons (there will be more content later). It executes OK except that there is a lot of wasted space between the entries. The list is very long so I wanted to remove this spacing:

[image]

```
<v-menu activator="#route-menu-activator" :close-on-content-click='false' title="Click to show route, double-click to select">
     <v-list density="compact">
        <v-list-item density="compact" v-for="(item, i) in Routes.list()" :key="i"  :value="i" >
          <v-btn variant='outlined' density="compact"  @click="viewRoute($event,i)">
             <span class="text-truncate" style="max-width:200px" >{{ DestinationString(item.dest) }}</span>
          </v-btn>
       </v-list-item>
     </v-list>
 </v-menu>
```

Using the `density='compact'` prop has helped a bit, but not enough. I have tried adding  `class="ma-0 pa-0"` to the `v-list-item` and to the button, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's some styling you want to achieve that props can't help with, just use CSS. Inspect the DOM, find the elements in question, and add CSS in your component's `<style>` tag that removes or reduces the padding/margin or height of those elements.

Inspecting v-menu list items in [this Vuetify Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) I found the below CSS properties help reduce the spacing between menu items.

```css
.v-list-item {
    min-height: 10px !important;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Though I'm still puzzled why adding the Vuetify class `ma-0 pa-0` doesn't acheive the same : seems  pointless having those classes when a bit of css is all that's needed.